# Errors in Zero-inflated glm model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation

I have a count data set with lots of 0 Zero-inflated data set
[image: zero-inflated dataset]

The dataset contains responds(which is the count data) and also three factors:temperature, food type, food concentration.

The data like:

```
foodtype quantity temperature count
Food3   Low     27  4
Food1   Medium  13  1
Food3   Medium  20  11
Food3   Medium  13  5
Food1   High    27  0
Food3   Medium  27  0
Food1   Low     20  0
Food1   Low     20  5
Food3   High    13  11
Food3   Medium  20  10
Food1   Medium  20  10
Food1   High    20  14
Food1   Medium  20  14
Food3   High    13  14
Food3   Low     20  3
Food1   High    27  6
Food3   High    27  9
Food2   Medium  20  21
Food2   High    20  24
Food1   Low     13  0
Food3   Low     13  0
Food3   High    20  19
```

I'm doing the Zero-Inflated Models with codes:

```
library(pscl)
mol<-zeroinfl(count~foodtype*quantity*temperature | count~foodtype*quantity*temperature,
dist="poisson", link="logit", data=mydata)
```

And the Erro shows:

```
Error in zeroinfl(count~foodtype*quantity*temperature | count~foodtype*quantity*temperature  : 
invalid dependent variable, non-integer values
```

Any ideas how to deal with the problem? Comments and solutions are high preciated! Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be using a LOGIT function for count data (and Poisson distribution). These two don't go together. Logit function is used for binomial data, while LOG function is typically used for the count data.

Comment: @Tilen The `link="logit"` is fine (and actually is the default in `zeroinfl`) as it pertains to the binary inflation submodel. @X.Chi The problem is that you repeat `count ~ ...` after the `|` which is not valid. You should use `count  ~foodtype * quantity * temperature  | foodtype * quantity * temperature`. Or, even simpler, `count  ~foodtype * quantity * temperature` because the terms in both submodels are the same. Finally, almost surely `dist = "negbin"` will lead to a much better fit because there seems to be overdispersion in the `count` response.

Comment: @AchimZeileis you're right, I forgot about that.

Comment: @AchimZeileis@Tilen, Dear AchimZeileis and Tilen, I really really appreciate your comments and answers. I run the model with dist="negbin", however, they gave a error:     Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.39927e-17
In addition: Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred. Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess that there is not enough variation in the data to estimate the three-way interaction you have specified.  Possibly there are some cell of food x quantity that have little or no variation in the count response.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thank you so much, Achim. I will check the dataset again, and I'm reading Alain Zuur's(2009) book, hope I can find solutions. Your suggestion above really helped me a lot! Best!